# How bright would cell phone towers appear to us if we could see in that range?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

And how bright would a phone appear during a phone call or networking activity?

Comment: The simplest correct answer would probably be "it varies quite a lot", for cell phone towers at least, because the power consumed by cell towers varies quite a lot. For a more in-depth explanation, see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/299889/how-much-power-is-radiated-by-cell-towers

Comment: If you are asking what the power emitted is then this has an answer. However I don't see how we can say how bright it would appear because that's based on some hypothetical perceptual model.